# Function Selection highlighter/wrapper is missing in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

When I put the mouse pointer inside a function, the entire function should be marked like the picture. But it is missing now. Please suggest me some fixes regarding this issue. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OL0Y.png

N.B: Currently I'm running VS Code 1.41.0 with Flatland Monokai theme.

Answer (score 1):

If by "marked" you mean the yellow line connecting the opening and closing bracket, then this is part of the [Bracket Pair Colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2) extension. There are two versions in the Marketplace, I am using version 0.0.29 and tested it with your theme.
The lines should be enabled by default, however, you might want to check your settings JSON for:

```
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.showVerticalScopeLine"
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.showHorizontalScopeLine"
```